# Bootstrap Input Textarea Row Sizing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The following is a tidbit of my code that lists different input fields.  The description is 256 characters, and I want there to be 2-3 rows instead of 1, and the width to be about twice as long.  I have delved in the css of bootstrap, and can only find out how to move the input box itself, not expand the textarea.  Does anyone know how to expand textarea in a form input field in bootstrap?

```
<div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($descriptionError)?'error':'';?>">
    <label class="control-label">Description</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input "name="description" type="text" placeholder="Description" value="<?php echo !empty($description)?$description:'';?>">
        <?php if (!empty($descriptionError)): ?>
            <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $descriptionError;?></span>
        <?php endif;?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap info :

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v2.3.2
 *
 * Copyright 2013 Twitter, Inc
 * Licensed under the Apache License v2.0
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Designed and built with all the love in the world by @mdo and @fat.
 */
```

Using textarea, and altering columns and rows, or width does not work

Comment: what about using a textarea instead of an input box?

Comment: you would think it would be that simple, but I changed that to no avail

Comment: use the textarea and set a width; you can do that with css or you can do it via the [cols](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_cols.asp) element for a textarea.

Comment: Post the Bootply code. That will help you get an answer.

Comment: @ManojKumar I added the bootstrap version, I don't know what you mean by "Bootply" code.  Thanks

Comment: Go here: http://www.bootply.com/new and input the generated HTML code of your problem not your PHP. Save it and give the link. Also update the code here.

Comment: @ManojKumar The site does not accept my code.  The code I have is utilizing php and sql to access a database, and will not run correctly on that site(no access to database).  No error is displayed.  I think this is something where a setting in the css is blocking the textarea display somehow, I will post the css.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some jQuery to resize on page load.
Change the input to a textarea and check out the following fiddle...not my code...

http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/m8Qk9/

```
(function($) {
$.fn.autogrow = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var textarea = this;
        $.fn.autogrow.resize(textarea);
        $(textarea).focus(function() {
            textarea.interval = setInterval(function() {
                $.fn.autogrow.resize(textarea);
            }, 500);
        }).blur(function() {
            clearInterval(textarea.interval);
        });
    });
};
$.fn.autogrow.resize = function(textarea) {
    var lineHeight = parseInt($(textarea).css('line-height'), 10);
    var lines = textarea.value.split('\n');
    var columns = textarea.cols;
    var lineCount = 0;
    $.each(lines, function() {
        lineCount += Math.ceil(this.length / columns) || 1;
    });
    var height = lineHeight * (lineCount + 1);
    $(textarea).css('height', height);
};
```

})(jQuery);

$('#test').autogrow();